Is it possible to remove the header chapter title prefix using the `titlesec` package?
In my book, the header is so far composed of the page number, and the chapter number and name, like this:

But I would rather have it only as "2. Life", i.e., without "CHAPTER", and no all caps, and ideally with less spacing between the "2" and the "Life".
Is it possible to do so with the package titlesec? So far, for customizing chapter titles, titlesec has been the simplest solution I've found, other solutions seem so convoluted...
Here's an MWE:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[paperheight   = 128mm, % ~A6
            paperwidth    = 105mm,
            bindingoffset = 5mm,
            left          = 4.5mm,
            right         = 9mm,
            top           = 15.2mm,
            bottom        = 15.2mm,
            footskip      = 6.35mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
            {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
            {\thechapter}
            {20pt}
            {\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{20pt}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \frontmatter
    \chapter{Preface}

  \mainmatter
  \part{Liberties}
    \chapter{Capture}
  \part{Life \& Death}
    \chapter{Life}
\end{document}


This isn't required for an answer, and I might create another question for these, but if you happen to have a quick solution:

How do you lift the contents of only the TOC?
And I wanted to remove the "Part" in the part titles, only having the roman numeral and the part title on two separate lines. Maybe there's something similar to what I did with the \titleformat but for part titles? (\partformat doesn't seem to exist.)


These are several questions. Please always ask only one question per question. For the first question: No. For the change of page [tag:header-footer] you usually use other packages like [tag:fancyhdr] or [tag:scrlayer-scrpage]. To change the chapter mark used in the page header, you usually redefine \chaptermark. See, e.g., Figure 3 in the fancyhdr documentation (and also try the tag links I've added to see related questions). And for the last one: Have you read the titlesec documentation, i.e. the last sentences of section 1 and the documentation of \titleformat?

The 2 last questions are optional. But thank you for the pointers.

Don't ask such optional questions. The chapter marks in the page header are completely independent from the contents of the ToC or the formatting of the part titles. So you break the question answer scheme of TeX.SX. Because of this such questions with several questions are often closed.

This question is similar to: Remove "chapter" keyword from header. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

That question seems pretty close, but one thing I find it weird is the face that having a preface in the \frontmatterwill then number it as 0, so the header will show something like "0. Preface", which I find weird.

As shown in two of the answers to the similar question: Remove "chapter" keyword from header, you can redefine \chaptermark to change the chapter mark used in page header:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[paperheight   = 128mm, % ~A6
            paperwidth    = 105mm,
            bindingoffset = 5mm,
            left          = 4.5mm,
            right         = 9mm,
            top           = 15.2mm,
            bottom        = 15.2mm,
            footskip      = 6.35mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
            {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
            {\thechapter}
            {20pt}
            {\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{20pt}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\if@mainmatter\thechapter. \fi#1}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \frontmatter
    \chapter{Preface}

  \mainmatter
  \part{Liberties}
    \chapter{Capture}
  \part{Life \& Death}
    \chapter{Life}
\end{document}

I use \if@mainmatter…\fi in the example to limit the output of the chapter number, the period and the space after the chapter number to the mainmatter.
However, this does not make the "CONTENTS" in the page header of the Table of Contents in lower case letters. To get this, you need a package like fancyhdr:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[paperheight   = 128mm, % ~A6
            paperwidth    = 105mm,
            bindingoffset = 5mm,
            left          = 4.5mm,
            right         = 9mm,
            top           = 15.2mm,
            bottom        = 15.2mm,
            footskip      = 6.35mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
            {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
            {\thechapter}
            {20pt}
            {\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{20pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\if@mainmatter\thechapter. \fi#1}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \frontmatter
    \chapter{Preface}

  \mainmatter
  \part{Liberties}
    \chapter{Capture}
  \part{Life \& Death}
    \chapter{Life}
\end{document}




This does work! Thank you very much! I'm getting this warning though, do you know how to fix it? Package fancyhdr: \headheight is too small (12.0pt):  (fancyhdr) Make it at least 12.1638pt, for example: (fancyhdr) \setlength{\headheight}{12.1638pt}. (fancyhdr) You might also make \topmargin smaller to compensate: (fancyhdr) \addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.1638pt}. If not that's ok. For reference, my project is now open source here.

I think that's happening because fancyhdr, the way you configured it, is shifting the header up a little bit.

Also, is there a way of making the chapter appear on the header on odd pages as well?

Ok, with respect to that warning, just following its recommended additions fixed things at least.

@psygo The warning is because of your geometry setting. You can use geometry option headheight to change the height of the head. Also read the fancyhdr documentation. I've already recommended Figure 3 of that documentation in my initial comment. If you read the explanation of \fancyhead, you would find, how to change the commands to use \leftmark on even and odd pages or how to change \chaptermark to initially use chapters for even and odd pages and sections only, if there are sections in the chapter. But this was not part of your question (even not optional).

Cool, thanks for the reference again. I think using what's on page 17 of that manual kinda solved things: \fancyhead[LE, RO]{\slshape\nouppercase\rightmark} \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape\nouppercase\leftmark}

There is the chaptermark and you can modify it, just with a simple command, without having to load precisely any package.
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}

If you decide to restore the uppercase format, input something like \MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1} within the first argument of the markboth command.
After the \frontmatter and the \backmatter commands, you have to repeat:
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{#1}{}}

To compare with other marker variants, see the fancyhdr package documentation, Users’ manual (English), p. 19.
I don't understand your second question: «How do you lift the contents of only the TOC?». Maybe, you are looking for the tocdepth counter: \setcounter{tocdepth}{x}. If x=1, you are telling to LaTeX to print in the table of contents only parts, chapters and sections; if x=2, you are telling to LaTeX to print also subsections. Indeed, the depth counters are: -1, to print only parts; 0, to print only chapters etc.
If you want «to remove the "Part" in the part titles», once again, there is to do just one command.
\renewcommand{\partname}{}

This should be enough, because by default the Table of contents doesn't consider the \partname when it itemises.
Here you are my MWE.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\partname}{}

\author{Mickey Mouse}
\title{A book}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\part{Put the title here}
\chapter{First Lipsum}
\section{Sublipsum}
\lipsum[1-19]
\end{document}


No, mine is just a misprint. Actually, I cited from the Italian pdf. You are right, the correct page is the 19th instead. I am going to correct the citation.

Done. Thanks for the check. @cabohah

Your answer is pretty close to what I wanted, but so far the main problem is the, if I use \frontmatter with a preface like I did in my example, then the preface gets written as "0. Preface" on the header, which I find strange. And, since Babel's version of Portuguese (\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}), I wasn't able to remove "Parte" with just \renewcommand{\partname}{}, although in English it does work. Strange.

What I mean by "lift" in this case is just shifting it up on the page, much like I did here for chapter titles: \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{20pt}, but for only the TOC title.

As I wrote in my answer, you have to repeat the \renewcommand{\chaptermark} after the \frontmatter command (and after the \backmatter one, in the case). Moreover, now I add also that, if you load the etoolbox package, you may also define, in the preamble, the \pretocmd{\frontmatter}{}{}{} command: in case, customise the chaptermark within the second couple of curly brackets; do it also for the \backmatter, in the case.

About the \partname problem: I didn't know about the portuguese language issue. Try to redefine the format of the part: \titleformat{\part}. Remove from this command the \partname command, because by default there is. See the titlesec package documentation, pp. 3-4.

Try to specify the \titlespacing command just before you input \tableofcontents.

Not \uppercase, please: use \MakeUppercase.

I'll try your comments tomorrow, @FrancescoContini . Thank you for all the help so far!

If you want more control on the page headings, use fancyhdr.
On the other hand, the patches to achieve your goals are easy.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\usepackage[
  paperheight   = 128mm, % ~A6
  paperwidth    = 105mm,
  bindingoffset = 5mm,
  left          = 4.5mm,
  right         = 9mm,
  top           = 15.2mm,
  bottom        = 15.2mm,
  footskip      = 6.35mm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% no Part in \part pages
\xpatchcmd{\@part}{\partname\nobreakspace}{}{}{}
% no Chapter in headings
\xpatchcmd{\ps@headings}{\@chapapp\ }{}{}{}
\pagestyle{headings}% apply the change
\makeatother

% modify the chapter headers
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {\thechapter}
  {20pt}
  {\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{20pt}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\frontmatter

\chapter{Preface}

\mainmatter

\part{Liberties}

\chapter{Capture}


\part{Life \& Death}

\chapter{Life}

\end{document}




Addendum
For hyperref the command to patch is not \@part, but \NR@part. You also need to put \tableofcontents after \frontmatter, where it actually always belong.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\usepackage[
  paperheight   = 128mm, % ~A6
  paperwidth    = 105mm,
  bindingoffset = 5mm,
  left          = 4.5mm,
  right         = 9mm,
  top           = 15.2mm,
  bottom        = 15.2mm,
  footskip      = 6.35mm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% no Part in \part pages
\AtBeginDocument{\xpatchcmd{\NR@part}{\partname\nobreakspace}{}{}{}}
% no Chapter in headings
\xpatchcmd{\ps@headings}{\@chapapp\ }{}{}{}
\pagestyle{headings}% apply the change
\makeatother

% modify the chapter headers
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {\thechapter}
  {20pt}
  {\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{20pt}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preface}

\mainmatter

\part{Liberties}

\chapter{Capture}


\part{Life \& Death}

\chapter{Life}

\end{document}


Your MWE works, thank you, but it seems that using the href package makes the "Part" in part titles to still remain. Strange.

@psygo See the Addendum

Now it works! Thank you @egreg!
